# Does dynamic programming always add one item per sub-solution?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

In the 0-1 knapsack problem, I am given a set of items with their weights and the weight that a knapsack can carry.

The objective is to maximize the number of items I can carry subject to the fact that I do not exceed the maximum weight of the knapsack.

The algorithm could be something as follows-:

```
weight = 0
list_of_items = {}
while weight < max_weight
for all remaining items present find one item that is equal to (weight + 1)
repeat until weight > max_weight
```

The key word here is "**find one item**".

This is my question, is it always true that we search for only 1 item each iteration for the next state/sub-solution ? Or can we search for multiple items ?

Will the next sub-solution always contain 1 value more than the previous one if it is possible to achieve ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, though this could affect the running time.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Most dynamic programs that I have seen till now only search for 1 new item to add the previous sub solution found. Wondering if that is the only way to go about constructing the ultimate optimal solution ?

Comment: Definitely not, you can also consider more elements. It just increases the running time of the algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yeah thats kind of my point. The optimal way of doing it is considering 1 new element per sub solution, right ? Considering more wouldn't be the correct/optimal way, right ?

Comment: @ng.newbie It would be difficult to prove that anyway to solve it is optimal considering knapsack's an NP-hard problem. It may be asymptotically better to choose 1 item at a time, however, probably not provably optimal.

Comment: @ng.newbie, however, if you are only trying to maximize the *number* of items included in your knapsack, rather than the profit (as is usual). Then, you simply iteratively take the item with minimum weight until you exceed capacity...

Comment: @ryan so you are telling me that there is no way to prove that taking one item at a time is optimal ?

Comment: @ng.newbie, with respect to time complexity, yes. With respect to optimality of the solution, you could prove it.

Comment: @ryan Could you please give me some insight as to how you would prove it for optimality ?

Comment: @ng.newbie, sorry, I mean you can prove that the solution your approach generates is optimal, but this can be done for many approaches as well. So you can't really say that "finding multiple items" is a non-optimal solution without further specifying how it works.

Comment: @ryan So just to confirm my understanding - you are saying that a particular solution can be shown that it is optimal if it picks one item, but there maybe also solutions that pick multiple items and still be optimal. In short DP does not dictate that you should always pick one element, also its not possible to show that picking only 1 element per sub problem is the only optimal solution. Am I correct ?

Comment: @ryan just out of curiosity how do you mathematically prove that an algorithm is optimal ?